# Marquee work in mail in email clients

Tags: email, email-client, marquee

I have a question related marquee element? is marquee or any Js function work in mail, like gmail, yahoo mail, outlook etc.

If yes than how please define.

Answer (score -1):

This is a blog post (from 2010) explaining `<marquee>` support in different clients:

http://stylecampaign.com/blog/2010/08/animating-emails-using-the-marquee-tag/

Notably, Gmail, Outlook and Thunderbird are not supporting this, but Yahoo and Hotmail are supporting.

Answer (score -2):

As far as HTML marquee element is concerened so Answer is yes because most email clients have ability to process HTML elements in BODY [here](http://stylecampaign.com/blog/?p=87) is an working example.Go through it.

if you wish to use advance JS then i think your needed javascript files must be located on server on the internet and you can use the javascript function animation etc in email body though i am not very sure but i think it should do like this.

I read somewhere that using scripts in your email may force your email/newsletter to be spammed by the email client so better not using it.

Alternatively if you wish to include common animations like image slideshow and you not having many images then using gif of your images may help you.
Thanks!!!